# Does Earth eclipse the Sun at the L2 Lagrange point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, geometry, solar-system

Is Earth's diameter large enough to eclipse the sun at the L2 [Lagrange point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point)?  Or does the sun shine around the edges of the earth?

I understand the useful area of the L2 Lagrange point is somewhat large.  Assuming an eclipse region exists at this distance, is some of the useful area outside of the eclipse region?

Comment: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/10355/  http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13585/  http://space.stackexchange.com/q/12116/

Comment: The sun does shine around the edges of the earth at the center of the L2 Lagrange point. [This answer from a different stackexchange site does the calcs.](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/10360/11065)